# Spresense SDKブートローダーのインストールについて

Tags: spresense

Spresense SDK スタートガイド (CLI 版)の環境構築手順説明にはブートローダーのインストールについて下記の説明があります。

> 適切なバージョンのブートローダーがインストールされていない場合、spresense/sdk ディレクトリの下で、 後述する
> tools/config.py 及び tools/flash.sh ツールを実行したときに次のような WARNING が表示されます。
> Install command: に書かれた内容に従ってインストールを行います。
>
> WARNING: New loader vX.Y.Z is required, please download and install.
> Download URL   : **https://developer.sony.com/file/download/spresense-binaries-vX.Y.Z.zip**
> Install command:
> 1. Extract loader archive into host PC.
> ./tools/flash.sh -e 
> 2. Flash loader into Board.
> ./tools/flash.sh -l /home/user/spresense/firmware/spresense -c

Download URLの部分については、Spresense SDKバージョンは2.0.0更新される前のものであり、2.0.0更新後、該当リンクがアクセスできなくなり、実際のWarningは下記のようなものになります。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
つまり、
**https://developer.sony.com/file/download/download-spresense-firmware-v2-0-000**
のほうは正しいということなので、
v2-0-000と従来の命名規則vX.Y.Zが一致していないことについて
ご確認お願いいたします。

Comment: このサイトはプログラミングに関する質問をする場となっております。製品の説明や仕様に関することは製品サイトでお尋ねください。もしプログラミングにおいて困っているということであればその旨も追記いただけると幸いです。

Comment: 「スタックオーバーフローユーザーへの質問(確認?)」ではない場合、製品サイトへお尋ね頂いた方が良さそうですね。

https://developer.sony.com/ja/develop/spresense/support/spresense-programming-support-on-stack-overflow

> 質問はプログラミングに関する事柄に限定してください。そして、多くの スタック・オーバーフローのユーザーから回答を頂けるように、質問に関するできるだけ多くの情報を記載するようお願 いいたします。

Comment: @harry0000 同じく製品サイトのヘルプページを眺めていましたが、製品サイトに問い合わせたい場合にどうすればよいのかが明記されていないように見えて、(僕らを含め) ユーザー視点では不親切だなと感じました。できれば Sony さんに改善を求めたいところです。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。ご指摘の内容に関して改善を検討いたします。

Answer (score 1):

ソニーのSPRESENSEサポート担当です。

ご指摘ありがとうございます。
Webドキュメントに記載されているダウンロードURLと実際のダウンロードURLとでフォーマットが異なっておりました。
こちら、誤解を生じさせない形での表現に変更いたしました。

ダウンロードURLはお使いの環境で表示された WARNING に記載されているものをお使いください。

今後ともSPRESENSEをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

SPRESENSEサポートチーム